# Firebase Database update/set causing wrong/inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a REST api with Firebase as my database and have a service /users which supports PUT to update an object users/:userId 
The object has the following structure

```
users : {
  user_id_1 : {
    user_name : 'BATMAN',
    user_photos : {
      'FBKEY1' : {
        'photourl' : 'https:...'
      },
      'FBKEY2' : {
        'photourl' : 'https:...'
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

FBKEY1 and FBKEY2 are generated using Firebase push and any client can perform update(PUT) operation on API : /users/user_id_1

example for changing the user_name I am calling the following from my client:

```
return usersFirebaseRef.child('user_id').once('value').then(function (snap) {
  var snapObject = snap.val();
  var user = {
    user_name : updateDataObjFromClient.user_name ? updateDataObjFromClient.user_name : snapObject.user_name,
    user_photos : snapObject.user_photos
  };
  return usersFirebaseRef.child('user_id').set(user);
});
```

Notice above I am just trying to update the user_name not the user_photos, the user_name property gets updated just fine **however the user_photos gets updated after a really long time (1min+) in firebase and 'FBKEY1' and 'FBKEY2' gets changed to something different (it's like the push happens all over again with new keys). I am not sure why is this happening. Also it's not always consistent i.e. sometimes the 'FBKEY1' and 'FBKEY2' don't even end up getting created in Firebase.** Not sure what am i doing incorrect.